# Creating Adjacency Matrix using SpatialLinesDataFrame and SpatialPointsDataFrame in R?

Tags: r, geometric-network, adjacency

I am trying to create an adjacency matrix of power plants that are connected via power lines. The plant data is point data (~8000 observations) with longitude and latitude measurements. The line data must have been mapped/drawn since it does not include specific location measurements.

I created 2 feature classes (one for power plants and another for power lines) and created a geometric network in ArcGIS in which many of the points snapped to the lines (there are ~7000 points that now intersect with lines). I believe the snapped/modified data was saved to the feature classes.

I imported the 2 feature classes into R using readOGR (as part of the rgdal library) and they converted into SpatialLinesDataFrame (for the power lines) and SpatialPointsDataFrame (for the power plants) classes. The import worked correctly since the plot appears to be exactly like that in ArcGIS. 
[image: Network Example]

The next step is to build an adjacency matrix (~7000x7000) where a 1 indicates a connection between two powerplants (data in the SpatialPointsDataFrame) via the intersecting powerlines (data in the SpatialLinesDataFrame) and a 0 otherwise. There are around 1000 plants that do not intersect with lines so these will either not be included in the matrix or will not have any connections.

Packages, such as shp2graph, can create adjacency matrices, but appear to only do so with SpatialLinesDataFrame (adjacency matrix that indicates where the lines intersect). I am wondering if there is a package/method that can make this adjacency matrix of points that are connected through lines. It is assumed that two plants are still connected even if they are through a series of intersecting lines.

Comment: So do you just need to map points to line segments with some tolerance and then test connectivity between line segments?

Comment: The points are already connected/snapped to line segments (if they were within 10,000 meters from a line). The points that are not connected to lines are considered not part of the network and I don't care if they are included in the adjacency matrix. I need to see which points that are on lines are connected to eachother through lines. I'm not quite sure what you mean by test connectivity between line segments

Comment: Once you've built your igraph structure you can see how many disconnected parts the graph is built from, and conclude that all points on any segment in the same part must be connected. That's what you want to know, isn't it?

Comment: Makes sense. The line data is recorded as ~66,000 separate line segments. If I find which plants intersect with a given line, I can assume that all of those plants are connected in the network.